# Preventing Time Machine from backing up website passwords

Tags: macos, osx-lion, time-machine, privacy-protection

I have been given a work machine (Mac Book Pro, Mac OS Lion 10.7.1). I am using Google Chrome's "remember password" feature.

Some of those passwords are personal (Hotmail, GMail...)  and I would like to prevent those from backing up.

How can I do this? Are there any other privacy-sensitive files or folders that would be a good idea to keep out of the work Time Machine loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can you exclude files from being backed up?

Open *System Preferences » Time Machine » Options*. Here, add folders that you wish to exclude.

[image]

These folders will not be backed up to your Time Machine disk.

---

#### What should you exclude?

Concerning privacy, the following would be a starting point. Note that this heavily depends on how far you take the meaning of "privacy" and how important your data is to you.

- `~/Library/Keychains/` – this is where (probably) all your login data is saved. Examine it with *Keychain Access.app*.
- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` – this is your entire Google Chrome profile.

Generally, OS X apps should store any kind of login information in the Keychain. Not all *need* to comply with this, so you can't generalize this in any way. Don't trust your backup to be completely safe. OS X Lion can encrypt your Time Machine backup – this is only one tier of protection though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about privacy, Chrome's password storage is less than optimal. Try something like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/products/1Password) that touts strong encryption.

Don't trust Time Machine exclusion rules for privacy in any way. Take the privacy [into your own hands](http://www.truecrypt.org/).